# how to remove everything after [/img] with regex?

Tags: regex

I have text as:

```
[img]http://cimislia.net/uploads/posts/2013-07/1373995142_vrc.png[/img]

[color=#3333FF]Дата выхода: 26 октября 2012
Жанр: Racing, Simulator, 3D
Разработчик: SCS Software
Издательство: Excalibur Publishing
```

I want to remove everything after `[/img]` so above text will be:

```
[img]http://cimislia.net/uploads/posts/2013-07/1373995142_vrc.png[/img]
```

Can somebody help please? How to do this with regex?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where are you using this?

Answer (score 1):

This regex

```
\[img\].*\[/img\]
```

will match only [img] tags and everything between.

How to use it depends on the programming language you are using.
Example in C#:

```
var text = @"[img]http://cimislia.net/uploads/posts/2013-07/1373995142_vrc.png[/img]

[color=#3333FF]Дата выхода: 26 октября 2012
Жанр: Racing, Simulator, 3D
Разработчик: SCS Software
Издательство: Excalibur Publishing
";

Regex regex = new Regex("\\[img\\].*\\[/img\\]");

var imgOnly = regex.Match(text).Value;
```

Comment: not working, it delete only everything between the images tag, but thats the only text i want to keep

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asks, but what the OP asks might not really be what the OP wants anyway. The OP asks to remove everything after `[/img]`, but doesn't say anything about removing anything before `[img]` like you've effectively done. Also, for the text `[img]a[/img]b[img]c[/img]`, the whole string will be matched: `.*` will match `a[/img]b[img]c` without any problem.

Comment: Because the regex is not removing but matching the content you want to keep, you can use it to extract the [img] tags

Comment: @HalilIbrahimUslu Your comment doesn't make sense. Are you searching for this regex, and removing its matches? This regex attempts to match what you asked for, so rather than removing the results, the results are what you should keep.

Answer (score 0):

you can search for `\[/img\](.|\n)*` and replace with `[/img]`